# Kate in Kubuntu 16.04 prompts every time there is a change in file

Tags: kubuntu, configuration, kde5, kate

I suffer from problem a problem in Kate in Kubuntu 16.04. Kate has an option for detecting changes in opened files. And if change has been detected Kate asks whether to update contents of file in editor, when I switch the focus on Kate.

The Problem is that since 16.04 it asks to reload even if another application is currently in focus. So it's just annoying. Old behaviour was that it only prompts only when you switch to Kate application.

For example, as I am working with version control system (using TortoiseHG): switch to some branch then merge changes from another branch and then again switch to branch and so on... And every time there is a change in file's content (because I don't want to close Kate) I get these nasty prompts whether I want or not want to reload changes. It makes me frustrated.

How could I restore the old behaviour? I don't want to turn off the entire file watch feature.

Comment: prompt in notification or in Kate?

Comment: This happens when documents changing on disk and Kate detects changes. It opens dialog where all changed files listed and gives you possibility to select opened files you want to update. Or you can ignore changes. Problem is that this window opening even if Kate is minimized and I work in another programme and I don't want this dialog appear and distract me from work. Could this be changed to old behaviour like in "normal" text editors? By normal behaviour I mean this dialog should appear only when I switch back to Kate app manualy.

Comment: I agree this is frustrating. I don't think this question should be in the kubuntu stackexchange though, it is not specific to kubuntu, it has either to do with Kate or KDE.

Answer (score 1):

Go to **Settings** -> **Configure Kate**, In Application -> **General** Tab, untick the option that says, *Warn about file modifications by foreign process* and hit Apply button. Now, Kate won't complain about file modification.

Here is a screenshot of the Settings page

[image: Uncheck option in Kate's Settings]

Comment: I know that I can completly switch this feature off by unchecking this flag, but it's not what I want. What I want is that Kate shouldn't open this dialog when Kate app is currently inactive. There was no such problem before I updated my Kubuntu distro into 16.04.

Comment: @UranuzCatDog Please test it. It won't turn off the feature. It is exactly doing you asked and I've tested before I wrote the answer

Comment: Nope. It doesn't do exactly what I want on my Kubuntu instance. It completly switches off the feature. It warns me only when I try to save file that was already changed by external app. But it's too late to me. I want it to warn me when I switch back to Kate from other app like it was doing in earlier versions (for instance Kubuntu 12 or 13)

Comment: Strange! In my test, if I keep this checked, whenever I change a file, the warning dialog pops-up. but when I uncheck this, it only complains when I switch to it. May be you've messed Kate's configuration? Try cleaning config file of Kate `~/.kde/share/config/katerc`